ath9k (wi-fi) driver doesn't work properly with new 24.04.1 LTS and kernel 6.8.0-48-generic
i have an issue with my WIFI
it works fine after reboot for 8-10 minutes but then it starts to reconnect, loses connection and so on
this issue started after kernel update on my old Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS and i found my WIFI working stable only on kernel 5.15.0-76-generic so i used it
when i upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS i hoped it will fix my issue, but even the last kernel 6.8.0-48-generic update did not help
i tried to copy driver folder from kernel 5.15.0-76-generic to the new kernel (ChatGPT helped), then i tried surfacego-wifi - no result
now i have two options

work on ethernet cable
switch to old OS/kernel

but i like new Ubuntu 24 so please help me to fix this issue
here are some details
my system parameters:

ASUS N551JW
Intel® Core™ i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 8
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M/PCIe/SSE2
RAM 16Gb

$ sudo dmesg | grep ath
[    2.174899] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/anydesk.service:9: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/anydesk.pid → /run/anydesk.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
[    2.250017] systemd[1]: Started systemd-ask-password-wall.path - Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    2.268147] systemd[1]: systemd-fsck-root.service - File System Check on Root Device was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=!/run/initramfs/fsck-root).
[    3.867601] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[    3.879154] ath: phy0: Set parameters for CUS198
[    3.879160] ath: phy0: Set BT/WLAN RX diversity capability
[    3.887376] ath: phy0: Enable LNA combining
[    3.889668] ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x42
[    3.889674] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x60
[    3.889676] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[    3.889678] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[    3.889679] ath: Regpair used: 0x60
[    3.903803] ath9k 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[  277.758788] audit: type=1107 audit(1730666769.211:210): pid=1383 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/timedate1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.125" pid=4251 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=4409 peer_label="unconfined"
[  277.759595] audit: type=1107 audit(1730666769.212:211): pid=1383 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/timedate1" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.125" pid=4251 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=4409 peer_label="unconfined"
[  336.001886] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  340.840702] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  346.176497] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  348.321570] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  353.720426] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x0000610c
[  360.759970] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  368.127641] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  371.303975] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  376.959554] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  381.741208] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  385.699023] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  391.814775] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  397.871560] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  401.798424] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  405.852222] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  412.909632] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  419.166673] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  423.829560] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x0000610c
[  430.707407] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  436.907634] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  440.868146] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  447.731070] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x00006100
[  454.801735] ath: phy0: DMA failed to stop in 10 ms AR_CR=0x00000024 AR_DIAG_SW=0x02000020 DMADBG_7=0x0000610e

$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2126]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k

$ uname -a
Linux N551JW 6.8.0-48-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 27 14:04:52 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 01
       serial: 28:c2:dd:d8:3f:c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=6.8.0-48-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7900000-f797ffff memory:f7980000-f798ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.1
       logical name: enp5s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: 08:62:66:b9:00:58
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-48-generic firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7814000-f7814fff memory:f7810000-f7813fff

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
05:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)

$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp5s0f1  no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"My_SSID"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 04:5E:A4:4D:92:82   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-32 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:980  Invalid misc:6   Missed beacon:0

$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no




GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=off"


this option seems working, i'm still testing

The following I consider to be high risk so following anything is at your own risk. I have not tried this myself.
A solution is suggested in the following thread by adding to kernel parameters
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230745
intel_iommu=off

It is also possible intel_iommu=igfx_off may work but depends on what hardware you have.
This parameter seems to be only needed to be set to "on" when using advanced Virtual Machine features like PCI pass-through, so disable it shouldn't be a problem in most cases.
Options are on off & igfx_off igfx_off [Default Off] By default, gfx is mapped as normal device. If a gfx device has a dedicated DMAR unit, the DMAR unit is bypassed by not enabling DMAR with this option. In this case, gfx device will use physical address for DMA.
Open a gnome terminal
Using your favoured editor (I use vi)
sudo vi /etc/default/grub #in the terminal
Goto line 10 (ish) Then modify the following: -
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

I hope this is of some help
To
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=off"

Save the update and run the following
sudo update-grub

Reboot.
You can confirm your modifications after the reboot by running cat /proc/cmdline and looking for the parts you added.
https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/exovc6/where_do_i_add_intel_iommuigfx_off/

thank u for your reply but it seems it didn't help.
here is my GRUB after modification:
--- start ---
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=igfx_off"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
--- end ---
and here is cat /proc/cmdline output after reboot:
--- start ---
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic root=UUID=37d1f999-6d49-405c-ba8c-a88bbba80e41 ro quiet splash
--- end ---
did i do something wrong?

You should see your mod when you typed 'cat /proc/cmdline' but you are not. Did you remember to run 'sudo update-grub'?

it appeared i had the other GRUB on the other older Ubuntu version and all my manipulations were overrided by the other GRUB config, so i re-installed my GRUB and now i have  this ~$ cat /proc/cmdline BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic root=UUID=37d1f999-6d49-405c-ba8c-a88bbba80e41 ro quiet splash intel_iommu=igfx_off 
... but it did not help and my issue persists

@wd3 See Karbanet Erol solution below. 'off' is a separate option. Options are 'on' 'off' & igfx_off'  igfx_off [Default Off] By default, gfx is mapped as normal device. If a gfx device has a dedicated DMAR unit, the DMAR unit is bypassed by not enabling DMAR with this option. In this case, gfx device will use physical address for DMA. https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/n805hc/is_it_valid_to_specify_intel_iommuxxxx_and_intel/
